# How to assign args value coming in the event handler to a variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a eventhandler like shown below. Here what I want to achieve is what ever value coming for `args.Name` I need to assign to `cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder` so that `cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder` will contain what ever value in the `args.Name` enclosed in `{}` that means `cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder = {args.Name}`. How to achieve this?

Following is the complete code:

```
Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    TestClass cls = new TestClass();
    cls.levelClassAssemblyBuilder =???
    return cls.levelClassAssemblyBuilder;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder?

Comment: i updated the type in my question

Comment: i simply want an assigning of value args.Name enclosed in parathesis{}  to cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder in such a way that cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder = {args.Name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
```

Comment: getting an error Error 4 No overload for method 'DefineDynamicAssembly' takes '1' arguments . What i did is i pasted your code after the code ManagedClass cls = new ManagedClass();

Comment: @rickymartin, updated the code. Also this code would go in place of cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder =???.

Comment: what is this NameAssemblyBuilderAccess and assembly ,two  errors showing that both are not exisitng in the context

Comment: @rickymartin, placed the comma in the wrong place. Updated the code. It should be assembleName and AssemblyBuilderAccess http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess.aspx

Comment: DefineDynamicAssembly constructor expects a AssemblyName as first argument and it can't take string. What do you mean it should be enclosed in parenthesis? Also, if it works fine, why that matters?

Comment: it worked, but now the issue is i am passing cls.UserClassAssemblyBuilder to the instance of Assembly, but why 'type ' becomes null. i have updated this code in my question